# How to get both tab completion and readline editing in mingw/msys shell?

Tags: command-line-interface, rxvt

I'm running msys 1.0 on Win2K using the rxvt.exe terminal. By default, tab-completion works, but when I do 'set -o vi' to enable vi-readline editing, tab-completion stops working. Surely I can have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-i": vi-complete
```

To enable it in the current session without having to restart it, type this at the Bash prompt:

```
 bind '"\C-i":vi-complete'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried both of these and I still have the same problem.

Comment: But wait! After doing the bind command, I found that if I also unchecked 'Quick-Edit' mode in the options tab of the msys.bat properties, then it worked! 

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After searching the mailing list, I added these lines to the top of my `.inputrc` file:

```
set editing-mode vi
TAB: complete
```

This seems to work for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Typing

```
set -o vi
```

followed by

```
bind '"\C-i":complete'
```

seems to give me the behavior I want (tab tab suggestions, and vi editing behavior).  This seems strange to me because

```
"\C-i":complete
```

is the default in the ~/.inputrc file.

Adding

```
"\C-i": vi-complete
```

to your

```
~/.inputrc
```

seems to work but only if there is a single suggestion, and tab tab does not give you a list of suggestions as it did before.  Does anyone have a more complete suggestion?

I tried:

```
$if mode=vi
      # "\C-i": complete
        "\C-i": vi-complete
$endif
```

But it as no effect if I switch to vi after I start mingw by typing

```
set -o vi
```

Of course

```
bind '"\C-i":vi-complete'
```

does work, but tab tab does not show all suggestions, and it only auto-completes if there is but a single suggestion.